# How to remove/run a pending job in Nomad?

Tags: nomad

There are some pending jobs in "$ nomad status" output. Is there a way to run a pending job?

```
$ nomad status
ID                                                                  Type   Priority  Status             Submit Date
5e74587392a49e5dca9c9c6d-0-build-1004018-z100-solid-octo-potato-14  batch  50        pending (stopped)  2020-03-20T14:45:24+09:00
5e74678bdb1df409005677d6-0-build-1004018-z100-solid-octo-potato-17  batch  50        pending            2020-03-20T15:49:48+09:00
5e746884db1df409005677dc-0-build-1004018-z100-solid-octo-potato-19  batch  50        pending            2020-03-20T15:53:56+09:00
5e746a02db1df409005677e3-0-build-1004018-z100-solid-octo-potato-20  batch  50        pending            2020-03-20T16:00:19+09:00
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pending means that it is about to run but something prevents it from it.

Try this:

- Check the status of a job, e.g. `nomad job status 5e74587392a49e5dca9c9c6d-0-build-1004018-z100-solid-octo-potato-14` to see if there are any messages that can make you understand what's happening.
- if the previous step doesn't help, Nomad creates allocations (set of tasks in a job should be run on a particular node). Their IDs will be visible in `nomad job status` output. You can check an allocation's status by `nomad alloc status $ID`, where $ID is the ID of an allocation.

As for removal of jobs, you can run `nomad job stop -purge 5e74587392a49e5dca9c9c6d-0-build-1004018-z100-solid-octo-potato-14` to remove the job from the job list.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. `nomad job stop -purge [ID]` command works as expected.